# Flutter - Json array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, object, flutter

How would I parse a nested array of objects such as the one below.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "message": "The request was successful",
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Abu Dhabi",
            "id": 4139,
            "parent": 5153,
            "type": "city",
            "imageURL": ""

        },
        {
            "name": "Croatia",
            "id": 5037,
            "parent": 6886,
            "type": "country",
            "imageURL": ""

        },
     ]
}
```

I am currently making an API call which returns data in the format as shown above.

My api call is as follows:

```
  Future<Location> getLocations() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('$endpoint/locations', headers: authenticatedHeader);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);

      // If server returns an OK response, parse the JSON.

      return Location.fromJson(responseJson);
    } else {
      // If that response was not OK, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }
```

I then have a location class as below:

```
class Location {
  String name;
  int id;
  int parent;
  String type;
  String imageURL;

  Location(
      {this.name, this.id, this.parent, this.type, this.imageURL});

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _locationFromJson(json);
}

Location _locationFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Location(
    name: json['name'] as String,
    id: json['id'] as int,
    parent: json['parent'] as int,
    type: json['type'] as String,
    imageURL: json['imageURL'] as String
  );
}
```

I am hoping to be able to retrieve all the locations above using a listview builder and create a listtile for each location.

How can I parse the JSON correctly?

Comment: `return Location.fromJson(responseJson.data);`

Answer (score 9):

Follor this url you will more idea about json parse.
https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51

Here is the code that what exectly you looking, i have use with static json in assets so you have to replace with your resonse.

```
    import 'dart:async' show Future;
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter_json/model/location_model.dart';

    Future<String> _loadlocationAsset() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/location.json');
    }

    Future loadLocation() async {
    String jsonLocation = await _loadlocationAsset();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonLocation);
    LocationData location = new LocationData.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(location.data[0].name);
    }
```

**Data model**

```
     class LocationData {
        final int code;
        final String status;
        final String message;
        final List<Data> data;

        LocationData({this.code, this.status,this.message, this.data});

        factory LocationData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){

            var list = parsedJson['data'] as List;
            print(list.runtimeType);
            List<Data> dataList = list.map((i) => Data.fromJson(i)).toList();


            return LocationData(
                code: parsedJson['code'],
                status: parsedJson['status'],
                message: parsedJson['message'],
                data: dataList
            );
        }
        }

        class Data {
        final int id;
        final int parent;
        final String name;
        final String type;
        final String imageURL;

        Data({this.id, this.parent,this.name,this.type,this.imageURL});

        factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
            return Data(
                id:parsedJson['id'],
                parent:parsedJson['parent'],
                name:parsedJson['name'],
                type:parsedJson['type'],
                imageURL:parsedJson['imageURL']
            );
        }
        }
```

Comment: use built value types for easy JSON serialization of complex objects.